# Compiling hadoop 1.0.3 word count code

Tags: java, hadoop, word-count

```
ayush@ayush-PC:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /home/ayush/Desktop/Hadoop-     WordCount/wordcount.jar Wordcount input output
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:115)
```

I am getting this error. I am using jdk1.7 and Hadoop1.0.3

Can anyone please tell how to get away with this error

Comment: you are running this program from the user ayush, did you setup hadoop from the same user? Did you give enough permissions to $HADOOP_HOME directory?

Comment: No i did not set up hadoop from the same user, rather I created another user hadoop as mentioned in the tutorial by andrew Noll.

Comment: can you tell me what it means to give enough permission to $HADOOP_HOME directory?

Comment: Then first switch user to hadoop,$su - hadoop  and run the jar from hadoop user

Comment: $HADOOP_HOME is the directory where you installed your hadoop jars, you have to set this as variable in your system. You should have done that as part of the tutorial.  You have to give permission to hadoop user , like chown.  Look over my tutorial here: http://students.cis.uab.edu/animeshj/hadoop/setuphadoopcluster.html

Comment: Thanks a Lot I got everything working now